# Raspberry PI with latest Mono

Tags: c#, winforms, mono, raspberry-pi

I would like to port some existing WinForms project into Raspberry PI but I'm having little success, mainly because it seems Mono's WinForms implementation has bugs in the TextBox widget.

After googling I found that this issue had actually been solved quite sometime ago, but the official version of MONO installed using `apt-get` is too old.

So I have tried numerous ways (which can be condensed into two) to upgrade my MONO to the latest version:

1. Add the Mono Project GPG signing key and the package repository to your system (http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/). Result: The installation is failed, and render my Raspberry PI useless. Have to re-install the official Raspbian image again
2. Try to build the latest version of Mono myself (https://gist.github.com/tonemackay/21139ff56c1e124659fa). Result: The compilation failed because of some type conversion bug in the Mono sources.

For the two methods above, I have tried numerous ways to solve it myself, but with no success.

Hope someone can give a better suggestion.

-- Update 24th Dec 2016

The error message is as below. I have searched the web, it seems like I can only install / compile the latest MONO in PI 2 or 3 but not PI 1. :(

```
Processing triggers for ca-certificates ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... 0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....Updating Mono key store
Illegal instruction
Done
done.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libglib2.0-cil
 libgtk2.0-cil
 libglade2.0-cil
 libnunit-core-interfaces2.6.3-cil
 libnunit-core2.6.3-cil
 libnunit-util2.6.3-cil
 libnunit-console-runner2.6.3-cil
 libnunit-framework2.6.3-cil
 libnunit-mocks2.6.3-cil
 libnunit-cil-dev
 libmono-cil-dev
 libwebkit1.1-cil
 mono-devel
 monodoc-browser
 mono-complete
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Given that this isn't really a coding problem, I suspect you'd be better off on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Messages like `The installation is failed` without adding more details, or `some type conversion bug` without adding the exact compiler error, are completely unhelpful in stackoverflow. Expect downvotes soon if you don't update your question to provide those details.

Comment: `apt-get install mono-devel` will install the latest mono - in case anybody comes across searching for an answer

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF 
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list 
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

If you have previous Mono version installed you need "apt-get dist-upgrade".

Comment: Thanks, you mean using dist-upgrade to replace the install mono-complete? I have mono-runtime installed previously, but not mono-complete.

Comment: yes I think you have to install with "mono-complete"